# how to search from a table populated from my database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL DB table as users.

I am populating a html table using php and ajax.(working fine)

but I want to search for specific data, written some code also, but not getting what is my mistake.

my index.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
                <h3>Product List</h3>
            <div id="users-grid">               
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
<script>
    function getresult(url) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){ $("#users-grid").html(data);}
       });
    }
    getresult("getresult.php");
</script>
```

my getresult.php(used to populate the #users-grid )

```
<?php 
    include 'database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $product = "";
    $queryCondition = "";
?>
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="index.php">

    <div class="search-box">
    <p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" name="product"  value="<?php echo $product; ?>"   />
    <input type="button" name="go" class="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="getresult('getresult.php')">
    <input type="reset" class="btnSearch" value="Reset" onclick="window.location='index.php'"></p>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Gross Price</th>
            <th>Profit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $queryCondition = "";
                if(!empty($_POST["product"])) {
                    $queryCondition .= " WHERE product LIKE '" . $_POST["product"] . "%'";
                }
                $orderby = " ORDER BY id desc"; 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users " . $queryCondition . $orderby;
                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['date'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['product'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['quantity'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['grossprice'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['profit'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                Database::disconnect();
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: PDO's great, but now see prepared statements

Comment: ANd what is your question?

Comment: how you send your post data?

Comment: i am able to display the table on my browser, but if i want to search anything from search box, the table is not showing filtered data.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will search anything start with your search query

```
$queryCondition .= " WHERE product LIKE '" . $_POST["product"] . "%'";
```

i think you should change it to this for haveing full search

```
$queryCondition .= " WHERE product LIKE '%" . $_POST["product"] . "%'";
```

when you put onclick on your submit button it will fire only when user click on the button but when user put something on text and press enter it will submit your form so you have to change your code to this

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" onsubmit="return getresult('getresult.php')">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" name="product" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["product"])) echo $_POST["product"]; ?>"   />
        <input type="button" name="go" class="btnSearch" value="Search">
        <input type="reset" class="btnSearch" value="Reset" onclick="window.location='index.php'">
    </div>
</form>
```

i changed input value to show your search query. and the return part is for stop page reload

and to send POST data you have to change your ajax code to this

```
function getresult(url) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {product: $('input[name=product]').val()},
        success: function(data){ $("#users-grid").html(data);}
   });
   return false
}
```

Comment: @kuljitk i please let me know if you have still any problem

Comment: @kuljitk is it fixed?